# How to align dynamic graphics and an image within an Overlay?

Tags: graphics, image, overlay, locator

I have dynamic graphics over an image but they won't line up, what am I doing wrong?

```
img = ExampleData[ExampleData["TestImage"][[1]]];
d = ImageDimensions@img;
pt1=d/4;pt2={d[[1]]3/4,d[[2]]1/4};pt3=3d/4;pt4={d[[1]]1/4,d[[2]]3/4};

MultiContourPolygon[polys_List] := Module[{contours = Append[#, First[#]]&/@polys}, 
    {Polygon@Join[Join@@contours,Reverse[First/@contours]],Line[contours]}
]

LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[{pt1,pt2,pt3,pt4}],
    Overlay[{img,
        Graphics[{Orange, Opacity[.4], 
            Dynamic @ MultiContourPolygon[{{pt1,pt2,pt3,pt4}, {{0,0}, {d[[1]],0},d,{0,d[[2]]}}}]},
            ImagePadding -> 0, ImageMargins -> 0, ImageSize -> d
        ]
        }, Alignment -> {Left,Bottom}, ImageSize -> d
    ]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the Plot Range:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[{pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4}], 
 Overlay[{Image[img, ImageSize -> 400], 
   Graphics[{Orange, Opacity[.4], 
     Dynamic@MultiContourPolygon[{{pt1, pt2, pt3, 
         pt4}, {{0, 0}, {d[[1]], 0}, d, {0, d[[2]]}}}]}, 
    ImagePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 400, 
    PlotRange -> Transpose[{{0, 0}, d}]]}, Alignment -> {Left, Left}, 
  ImageSize -> 400]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks! I knew I was missing something simple.

Comment: @M.R. Mma has a lot of alignment options ... this kind of thing are sometimes easy ... sometimes not so

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do that is to use `Show`:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[{pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4}], 
 Show[Image[img], 
  Graphics[{Orange, Opacity[.4], 
    Dynamic@MultiContourPolygon[{{pt1, pt2, pt3, 
        pt4}, {{0, 0}, {d[[1]], 0}, d, {0, d[[2]]}}}]}, 
   ImagePadding -> 0]]]
```

[image]

With this solution you do not have to specify any `PlotRange` or `ImageSize`.

Answer (score 2):

This is related to this recent question:
 [relative scale of elements in ImageCompose](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18503/121)

My answer is similar:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[{pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4}],
 Show[
  Rasterize @ img,
  Epilog ->
   {Orange, Opacity[.4], 
    Dynamic@MultiContourPolygon[{{pt1, pt2, pt3, pt4}, {{0, 0}, {d[[1]], 0}, 
        d, {0, d[[2]]}}}]}
 ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This way there is no need to mess with `ImagePadding`, `ImageMargins`, `ImageSize`, `Alignment`, `PlotRange` or any such options.